# Building a Typesafe Decorator

Tags: typescript

I'd like to build something that I call a typesafe decorator (for the lack of a better term)

```
class Implementor implements T {
    public constructor(x: T) {
         Object.assign(this, x)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to convince the Typescript compiler that `assign`ing an instance of `T` will make `this` also an instance of `T`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that well-versed with TypeScript, but I think it's only possible with dirty tricks:

```js
class Implementor {
    public implement<T>(x: T): Implementor & T {
        Object.assign(this, x);
        return this as unknown as Implementor & T;
    }
}

class Foo {
    public bar = "test";
}

const foo: Foo = new Foo();

const impl1: Foo = new Implementor().implement(foo);
console.log(impl1);

const impl2: Implementor = new Implementor().implement(foo);
console.log(impl2);
```

Working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECSC2AHEBTeKB2AXA9gJ2gG8AoaM6RAVwCMQBLYaOpVdbAHgBUA+ACgA8AXNE4BKYQmRpMuAgDIRRUuRUB5agCsUwLADpIEOgHMMvLAAs6EADTR+ogNzKVZPCiyU8GaBavRI0JQYANYYOADu3gGSrDL40AqcTioAvsRpxKAG0ABiODhKKlS0DNDUYAQAvNAARFgoEFg1ThnAOBiN0ABm+cJ5BdUYKOG5+byOxJntnczIAIx9+dCDw3As0tj447qzsdi8PTgTbR04qLogOEa8u3MTUx1YTCwATBLrbLLL0EMjMRuyba7AEHfLHaZnFAXK43V4TMhAA).